# TSQL not causing infinite loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the code below:

```
declare @crimeurn varchar(20)
DECLARE @finalresults TABLE (crime_urn varchar(20))
DECLARE @potentialresults TABLE (crime_urn varchar(20))

insert into @finalresults values ('1')    

DECLARE finalresults_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT crime_urn FROM @finalresults
OPEN finalresults_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM finalresults_cursor INTO @crimeurn

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    print @crimeurn  

    INSERT INTO @finalresults
    values ('2')

    FETCH NEXT FROM finalresults_cursor INTO @crimeurn
END 

select * from @finalresults --line 16

CLOSE finalresults_cursor 
DEALLOCATE finalresults_cursor
```

Line 16 displays 5137 or 12,342 rows in SQL studio manager (it randomly varies).  I expected the TSQL to cause an infinite loop because there is an insert into the table variable on every iteration of the cursor.

Why does it not cause an infinite loop? i.e. why are there 5,137 or 12,342 rows returned.

Comment: to make it clearer, the behavior, you should change the insert in the cursor with @crimeurn+1 instead of '2' and remove the @potentialresults, it is not used

Comment: Why in the world would you use a cursor to insert data in the first place?

Comment: @Sean Lange, The business problem is this: crime a links to crime b, which links to crime c, which links to crime x.  I do not know how many links there are in each chain.  Therefore a cursor insert was the only way I could see of doing it.

Comment: That sounds like typical recursion to me. A recursive cte would surely be better than a cursor here.

Answer (score 3):

You are inserting into a heap.

A heap is unordered. There is no particular guarantee that the row will be inserted after the current row and picked up on the next fetch.

I made a slight amend to your test framework and added an IDENTITY column. In my case it got to row 592,353 before terminating.

As you can see from the results below this final row happened to be inserted on an earlier page in the file (jumped from 1623 to 184) so an allocation ordered scan starting from the penultimate row wouldn't find it.

[image]

Code to reproduce.

```
declare @crimeurn varchar(20)
DECLARE @finalresults TABLE (crime_urn varchar(20), ID int identity)
DECLARE @potentialresults TABLE (crime_urn varchar(20))

insert into @finalresults values ('1')    

DECLARE finalresults_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT crime_urn FROM @finalresults
OPEN finalresults_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM finalresults_cursor INTO @crimeurn

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    print @crimeurn  

    INSERT INTO @finalresults
    --OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
    values ('2')

    FETCH NEXT FROM finalresults_cursor INTO @crimeurn
END 

select *, sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%) from @finalresults --line 16
ORDER BY ID

CLOSE finalresults_cursor 
DEALLOCATE finalresults_cursor
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by heap? I know the difference between the stack and the heap in .net.

Comment: a [table without a clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx). Though to be clear even if you had a CI you would need it to not allow duplicates and have an `ORDER BY` on the key columns to get deterministic results. For example changing the table definition to `DECLARE @finalresults TABLE (crime_urn varchar(20), ID int identity primary key)` and the select to `SELECT crime_urn FROM @finalresults order by ID` should run indefinitely.

Comment: A [Link with notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/09/19/761437.aspx) on how order not guaranteed for heap inserts vs reads.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The information below is wrong, but I've left it because that's how I believe it's *supposed* to work.

By default, cursors do not run in `INSENSITIVE` or `STATIC` mode.  By default cursors are `DYNAMIC` and `OPTIMISTIC`.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) on cursors doesn't mention how dynamic cursors behave with respect to `INSERTS`.  `INSERT` behavior appears to be undocumented.

You may be able to fix this with the `SCROLL_LOCKS` option, which guarantees order preservation.

---

Because the cursor's definition is fixed when you run

```
DECLARE finalresults_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT crime_urn FROM @finalresults
```

It's static after that point.  Updating the table variable `@finalresults` doesn't change the cursor `finalresults_cursor`.

It's like this:

```
X = 10
Y = X
X = 20
PRINT X, Y
```

Outputs this:

```
20        10
```

Comment: Surely that would mean that one row is returned rather than: 5137 or 12,342.  I am pretty certain that the @finalresults_cursor can increase in size as you loop through it.

Comment: @w0051977 `@finalresults_cursor` doesn't exist.  You have a cursor called `finalresults_cursor` and a table variable called `@finalresults`.  Your loop modifies `@finalresults`.  `finalresults_cursor` remains static.  It's not dynamically updating.

Comment: Thanks.  Why are there 5,137 or 12,342 rows returned then?

Comment: @w0051977 Hm.  Maybe I'm wrong.  I guess I haven't actually tried this.  My next guess would be that at some point the next row doesn't get inserted where the cursor expects the next row to be.

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, I'm wrong.  I've only ever done `STATIC` cursors or in a few instances I've done dynamics but only run `UPDATE` and `DELETE` on the base table.  I didn't think `INSERT`s would propagate.  I don't see any doc on `INSERT`.  Any behavior might be unpredictable.

Comment: Since the example table has no Clustered Index, it is a heap table. A heap table doesn't guarantee that the read order is same as insert order when there is no order by ([Link with notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/09/19/761437.aspx)).  I don't believe cursor options can work around that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

However, if you do not care or know the type of the cursor, you can use the `@@CURSOR_ROWS` inside your loop to do some "cursor" logic :) . 
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176044.aspx) is some documentation on the possible values the `@@CURSOR_ROWS` variable can have, depending on the cursor's type: .